# tkinter background color will not change on Mac M1

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I haven't a clue why not but this won't change the background color

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Swiperino Desktop")
        self.root.geometry("400x250")
        self.root.configure(background="white")
        self.root['background'] = "white"

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.run()
```

Comment: Please update your question with your environment information `tkinter patchlevel` `python version`

Comment: There are some differences, you might find the answer [here](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tk+differences+on+Mac+OS+X)